# Need xslt attribute to create/format table with only outer border , no column separating border

Tags: xslt

I have a table with 2 columns and multiple rows. I need to have only the outer border of the table and nothing as column separator. I could not find any attributes.

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="Cell-Default">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-color">rgb(175,175,175)</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">thin</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-bottom-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-right-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="start-indent">.1cm</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="end-indent">.1cm</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row height=".9cm" display-align="center" background-color="rgb(235,235,236)">
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="Cell-Default">
<fo:block>
<fo:inline color="rgb(0, 0, 0)">QUOTE NUMBER: </fo:inline>
<fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="../QuoteNumber"/></fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
```

Comment: Post input, required output and XSLT tried code...

Comment: Sounds like something to do in HTML, not XSLT. What is your input? What is your output? Please describe both and give examples. Are you trying to transform some kind of XML input into output which is rendered with the described attributes?

Comment: Please provide an [mre] of sample input and your own best attempt to program towrds the decribed goal.